# Databinding a combobox to a Collection

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, collections, combobox

I have a normal asp.net combobox on my web page. The current version is databinding a a datatable object, but I want to change it so that it databinds to a Collection but I am getting errors.

I've tried  using an ObjectDataSource, but they have CRUD commands that I don't need.

So the question is... How can I databind an asp.net combobx to a collection ? Do I need to convert it to a list (possibly time-consuming) or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every object whose type inherits IEnumerable can be bound to any object that supports databinding, so just do

```
object.DataSource = collection;
object.DataBind();
```

and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can always assign a collection to the data source property of combobox

Answer (score 0):

With an ASP.NET combobox you'll want to set the DataValueField and DataTextField fields as well.

```
cboBox.DataSource = collection;
cboBox.DataTextField = "Name";
cboBox.DataValueField = "ID";
cboBox.DataBind();
```

That should get your data to display how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for your answers.

The error I was getting was The DataSourceID of 'controlname' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource

I was databinding as you suggested

```
this.combobox.DataSource = userCollection;
this.combobox.DataTextField = "Name";
this.combobox.DataValueField = "UserId";
this.combobox.DataBind();
```

But I figured out that the DataSourceID property had been set in the Designer View, so I removed that and everything began working normally :)